# meta query not retrieving posts

Tags: custom-post-types, php, advanced-custom-fields, get-posts

I am attempting to use get_posts() to retrieve posts that have certain topics attached to them, in my custom post type named 'leaders'

Here is my query.

```
$args = array(
    'post-type' => 'leaders',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => 'topics',
     'value' => '1773',
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);

$test = get_posts( $args );
```

If I var_dump the posts meta data i get this

```
topics  a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1773";i:1;s:4:"1783";i:2;s:4:"1763";i:3;s:4:"1753";}
```

However my get_posts just returns null, can anyone see why?

Answer (score 1):

One problem here is that you have written `post-type` with a hyphen when it should be with an underscore, like this `post_type`.

So, this should get your post data back:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'leaders',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'topics',
            'value' => '1773',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$test = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Good spot ;-)